# redim property in class module

Tags: vba, properties

I am pretty new to using classes in vba. I am trying to use an array as a property where the length of the array has to be variable. I was looking around for a way to do that, but I dont really understand how those properties work.

so I define my array in the class module

```
Private pTestArray() As String
```

and the properties to get and set values

```
Private Property Get TestArrayValue(index As Long) As String
    TestArrayValue = qTestArray(index)
End Property

Private Property Let ArrayValue(index As Long, strValue As String)
    pTestArray(index) = strValue
End Property
```

but I cant find a way to redim the array. any clues?
Thanks
C

Comment: Please use the code button `{}` to format your code and make your posts legible.

Answer (score 5):

So you want to resize on assignment? then you can check & handle the bounds in the `Let` property;

```
Private Property Let ArrayValue(index As Long, strValue As String)
    If index > UBound(pTestArray) Then ReDim Preserve pTestArray(index)
    pTestArray(index) = strValue
End Property
```

You will also need to initially dimension with `redim pTestArray(0)` in the `Class_Initialize` event.